# Passing a pointer to a pointer to a string with IDA Pro's Appcall

Tags: ida, idapython, idc

I need to call an encryption function in a program with the following signature (the second argument is returned):

```
char** __usercall decode(char** input, char** output)
```

As far as I can tell, [Appcall](https://hex-rays.com/blog/introducing-the-appcall-feature-in-ida-pro-5-6/) should be used for this kind of thing. There's an [example](https://hex-rays.com/blog/practical-appcall-examples/) given for functions that take pointers to character arrays, but there's no documented way to use functions that take pointers to pointers to character arrays.

How can I do this?